# php replace all links using regex with blank

Tags: php

The following code to remove all HTML links in `$content` is not working:

```
$content = str_replace('/<a href=.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/', '', $content);
```

If I use it on a single domain or single string than it works.

```
$content = str_replace('http://youtube.com', 'http://example.com', $content);
```

Comment: Use DOMDocument instead. A regex can probably solve this but php's dom parser is a better way to do html replacements https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
<?php
$content = "this is a sample <a href=\"\">link</A> end";
$result=preg_replace('/(<a .*href=["\'])([^> ]*)([\'"]>)([^<]*)(<\/a>)/i', '\1http://www.example.com\3\4\5', $content); 
echo $result;
?>
```